# call jquery function within "a" tag "onclick"

Tags: jquery

here is my code:

```
<a href='P001' class='basic'>Read More</a><br>
<a href='P002' class='basic'>Read More</a><br>
<a href='P003' class='basic'>Read More</a><br>
```

my script:

```
$('.basic').click(function(id){
   $.ajax({
       url: 'display_pro.php?id='+$('.basic').attr('href'),
       success: function(data) {alert(data);}
   });
});
```

when i click all links it's always get the 'P001'.
what is the problem?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('.basic').click(function(e) {
   var link = this; // <-- best practice
   $.ajax({
       url: 'display_pro.php?id=' + link.href, // use link here...
       success: function(data) {alert(data);}
   });
   return false; // <-- needed, prevents page from jumping into another page..
});
```

Comment: was just about to mention the same. Too many producers :P. Sad nobody cud realize that the ajax call is asynchronous (by default). So even before browser processes it, it will first return from the event handler and hit the url specified in the "href" property, can't ignore that. So, as it turns out that AJAX call never happened.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `+$('.basic').attr('href')` you should do:

```
$(this).attr('href')
```

Otherwise, you are asking again for the set of items with the class as "basic" and grabbing the value of the first one. `$(this)` (or `e.target`) ensure you are getting the currently clicked item. Also, FYI, the argument passed to the function is not `id`--it is an event object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **$(this).attr('href')** instead of **$('.basic').attr('href')**

```
 $('.basic').click(function(id){
      $.ajax({ 
           url: 'display_pro.php?id='+$(this).attr('href'), 
           success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
           } 
      }); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, please put your code inside of code ticks ``

```
<a href='P001' class='basic'>Read More</a>
<a href='P002' class='basic'>Read More</a>
<a href='P003' class='basic'>Read More</a>
```

Here's the answer:

```
$('.basic').click(function (id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'display_pro.php?id=' + $(this).attr('href'), //use $(this) so it knows which link you clicked on
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```